# Why my scrapy downloader middleware do not render javascript properly?

Tags: javascript, webkit, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I am using [this scrapy code snippet](http://snipplr.com/view/66996/renderedinteractive-javascript-with-gtkwebkitjswebkit/) to render javascript code of the website that I want to crawl data from. The site is a video search engine and the search results is rendered by javascript. I want to follow the next page link and scrap the whole searched items. Following is my spider code:

```
class VideoSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "VideoSpider"
    allowed_domains = ["domain.com"]
    start_urls = ['video search results link']

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        video_items = hxs.select("//ul[@id='results-list']/li[@class='result']")
        #items = []
        for vi in video_items:
            item = VideoItem()
            link = vi.select("a[@class='result-link']/@href").extract()[0]
            title = vi.select("a[@class='result-link']/@title").extract()[0]
            #print title,link
            item['title'] = title
            item['url'] = link
            yield item

        next_page = hxs.select("//div[@id='page']/a")
        for np in next_page:
            next_url = np.select("@href").extract()
            if next_url:
                url = urlparse.urljoin(response.url, next_url[0])
                #url = response.url, str(next_page)
                self.log("find next page url: %s"%url, log.INFO)
                yield Request(url, callback=self.parse)
```

I found that the link in the `start_urls` is correctly downloaded and rendered properly like this:

```
<ul id="results-list" class="clearfix" static="bl=normal">
    <li class="result" href="" </li>
     <li class="result" href="" </li>
     <li class="result" href="" </li>
    ....
```

Therefore the  extracting is successful on the first page while when the next page links is fetched the javascript is not rendered like this:

```
<ul id="results-list" class="clearfix" static="bl=normal"></ul>
    <div id="loading">trying to load page for you, please be patient</div>
```

So the scraping stopped because it can not extract the links as a result of the `results-list` is not rendered.Why the first page is rendered properly but the second is not? Should I use `selenium` instead of `webkit and jswebkit`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figure out the problem. Some url are not properly formed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert but I've recently fell in love with Scrapy and Selenium.   I used to scrape hardcore with perl and python mainly with urllib2/beautifulsoup/regex/mechanize but ran into what I felt like were impossible sites to deal with, sites extensively using ajax with no data to be pulled from the source.  Sites that could not even be broken with masking post request parameters, so for awhile I gave up on my scraping hopes and dreams.

It took me a little bit, but now I'm using Selenium with Webkit and it's amazing. I feel like a pro hacker.

In fact I'm pretty confident most sites cant stop me.   It perfectly emulates the user using the browser, I just use sleep to make sure I allow the page ajax to load correctly. For difficult sites like Amazon just don't be greedy, makes your hits randomly spaced out.  I've had selenium running for days with no problems.

I would definitely recommend you look into selenium.  Everything uses Ajax nowadays.

Comment: You say you're using Selenium with Webkit? Do you mean Selenium with PhantomJS as webdriver?